# How can I access OuterClass field from InnerClass?

Tags: java, class, inner-classes, anonymous-class

I've been learning Java and OOP for a few weeks now.

Yesterday I learned inner class and outer class. I want to know the way to access field of outerClass from InnerClass when they have exactly same name.

Like below, It is possible to access field of outerClass from innerClass when they have different names.

```java
public class OuterClass { 
    public String OuterName;
    public OuterClass(String OuterName) {
        this.OuterName = OuterName;
    }
    public class InstanceInnerClass {
        public String InnerName;
        public InstanceInnerClass(String InnerName) {
            this.InnerName = InnerName;
        }
        // In this method, accessing field in outer and inner class is possible. 
        // when they have different name.
        public void printAllName() {
            System.out.printf("OuterName: %s, InnerName: %s\n", OuterName, InnerName);
        }
    }
}
```

When they have same name, I don't know how to access both names.

```java
public class OuterClass { 
    public String name; // field which has same name
    public OuterClass(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public class InstanceInnerClass {
        public String name; // field which has same name
        public InstanceInnerClass(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public void printAllName() {
            // What should be written in this code 
            // to print both name fields from OuterClass and InnerClass
            System.out.printf("OuterName: %s, InnerName: %s\n", name, name);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply by doing `OuterClass.this` and the name of the field from the `OuterClass` that you want to access, for instance `OuterClass.this.OuterName`. In your code would look like the following:

```
public class OuterClass {
    public String name; // field which has same name
    public OuterClass(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public class InstanceInnerClass {
        public String name; // field which has same name
        public InstanceInnerClass(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public void printAllName() {
            // What should be written in this code
            // to print both name fields from OuterClass and InnerClass
            System.out.printf("OuterName: %s, InnerName: %s\n", name, OuterClass.this.name);
        }
    }
}
```

When you have two fields with the same name one in the inner class and the other on the outer class (*i.e.,* shadowing), and you try to access from the inner class that field, the compiler assumes that you want to access the field from the inner class, and ignores the other from the outer class. Otherwise, it would be impossible to choose, which variable to use.

**[Shadowing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)**

> If a declaration of a type (such as a member variable or a parameter
> name) in a particular scope (such as an inner class or a method
> definition) has the **same name as another declaration in the enclosing
> scope**, then the declaration shadows the declaration of the enclosing
> scope. **You cannot refer to a shadowed declaration by its name alone.**

Answer (score 3):

The fields of `OuterClass` are accessible in `InnerClass` via `OuterClass.this`:

```java
public void printAllName() {
    // to print both name fields from OuterClass and InnerClass
    System.out.printf("OuterName: %s, InnerName: %s\n", OuterClass.this.name, this.name);
}
```

Test:

```java
OuterClass outer = new OuterClass("myOuter");
OuterClass.InstanceInnerClass inner = outer.new InstanceInnerClass("myInner");

inner.printAllName();
```

prints:

```
OuterName: myOuter, InnerName: myInner
```